# OnMouseDown function if and else does not work

Tags: game-physics, unity-game-engine

I am doing unity project. i want an object to go up when i click on it. it goes but when it rolls over (when rotation.z is higher than 90 and lower than 275) it goes down instead up. So i have to add negative thrust so object goes up. But the game doesn't seem to detect it or this function doesn't support it. Any suggestions how would i fix that?

**FIXED!!** I just had to replace `transform.up` with `Vector3.up`.

```
void OnMouseDown(){
        if(this.transform.rotation.z > 90 && this.transform.rotation.z < 275 ) {
            rb.AddForce (transform.up * -thrust);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = Random.insideUnitSphere * 2;
        }
        else 
        {
            rb.AddForce (transform.up * thrust);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = Random.insideUnitSphere *2;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Vector3.up instead of transform.up? This would ensure the thrust direction is up (0,1,0) relative to the world.

Comment: yeah it solved the problem thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `this.transform.rotation.z` returns a Quaternion value, not rotating angles presented by euler angles.To see what is Quaternion look [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html). Also check out [this documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) about rotation. For actual angles try `transform.rotation.eulerAngles`